# nuxt generate throws error for dynamic page nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I can not seem to figure out what the issue is here...

I have created a blog with pagination using nuxt.js now in my `nuxt.config.js` I have a method that gets the posts from contentful like so

```
const getBlogPosts = async () => {
  let blogPosts = await client.getEntries({ order: '-sys.createdAt', limit: 1000, content_type: config.CTF_BLOG_POST });
  return blogPosts;
};
```

then when I generate the routes I do the following...

```
generate: {
    routes: async () => {
      const posts = await getBlogPosts();
      const routes = [];
      let postsNum = Math.ceil(posts.items.length / 10); // get the page numbers
      for (let i = 1; i <= postsNum; i++) {
        routes.push({
          route: '/page/' + i,
          payload: {
            data: posts.items.splice(i === 1 ? 0 : i * 10, 10)
          }
        });
      }
      return routes;
    }
  },
```

then in my `_page/index.vue`

[image]

```
<script>
export default {
    components: {
     //...
    },
    aysnc asyncData(context) {
        if(context.payload) {
            return {
                blogPosts: context.payload.data.items.slice(0, 8)
            }
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

now when Im running this locally the page works fine no errors etc.. but on `nuxt generate` I get

`ERROR: Error generating /page/1`

now I've tried to `console.log()` the blogPosts on `mounted()` but It never fires.

I can not figure out what is wrong here, Ive tried to strip back everything and made my `_page/index.vue` to look like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

but I still get the generate error I've `console.log()` routes and I get this

```
[                                                                                                 11:39:44  
  {
    route: '/page/1',
    payload: {
      data: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

which looks correct, so why is the page erroring??

**edit 1**

When I check my dist folder the page 1 index.html is there but in the html it says `this page could not be found`

any help would be appreciated thanks or is there a way to get a better error message

**edit 2**

All of my individual blog pages build correctly, but the actual /page/1 is the only one that is failing I have put a try catch around the whole async generate method and there are no errors.. also If I console.log all the routes it appears as if it is all correct

```
[                                                                                                 08:58:38
  {
    route: '/blog/6gQUEUwex7mjNtAXY4ZlTO',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/2xDAv0zSt4kUfxOV1XC98C',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/6f6shGDflvuBUMZn25sIbE',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/24Sov29BazGj52WEQdJGiy',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/r2ky97Vg8u6rouiVXdSzd',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/2QnIl7GOScQ31A7EcRVgT1',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/1bEUOT5Xnm7CU9Njd5xkeu',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/blog/7FUON1DcQcGQnvdp7Kxfbe',
    payload: {
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    route: '/page/1',
    payload: {
      data: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

all of the other pages are generated correctly

Comment: `console.log()` won't work unless in development mode, use `console.error()...` if you must

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `console.error()` didnt do anything either, If i put a console.log() on any other route, while its generating it will display it

Comment: @SmokeyDawson can you add some try/catch blocks to each of your `await` statements and see if you are getting any errors as a result of the async calls?

Comment: @ChrisLeyva I will try this and update my question, thanks

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I also added some more info to your question in the Nuxt reddit thread you posted.

Comment: @ChrisLeyva sorry for late response been working on other projects, I have put try catch blocks around the code and still no errors show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am an idiot..

The route that needed to be generated was `/blog/page/1` not `/page/1`

so I updated this

```
for (let i = 1; i <= postsNum; i++) {
  routes.push({
    route: '/blog/page/' + i,
    payload: {
      data: posts.items.splice(i === 1 ? 0 : i * 10, 10)
    }
  });
}
```

Once that was fixed.. it built correctly!

Make sure to triple check your generated route names...